# Why do I see such a black screen in TikzEdt?

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors

I downloaded TikzEdt and installed it.

At beginning, everything is normal. But now, I can' t see the lines to write code. There is just black screen.

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Which TikzEdt version are you using and on which operating system? Unfortunately, I think TikzEdt project is no more maintained :'(

Comment: I use on TikzEdt 0_2_3 on windows 10. There is nothing to do, really? :(

Comment: I have the same version on the same OS, when I get some problems I uninstall and reinstall TikzEdt (classical dirty fix on Windows...) and generally it works, you may have a try but I don't assure you that it works in your case...

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled it, but I live still same problem. I don' t understand what is the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you, it's a pity because I think TikzEdt is the best TikZ editor! :'(

Comment: Stupid question: have you opened a document?

Comment: Yes, I opened. But there is no change. There is still black screen

Comment: And have you tried to do a new file?

Comment: Yes I have tried to create a new file to. But it's same. Thank you very much for your interest:)

Comment: No hope, then! :'(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52681/discussion-between-hd239-and-carlatex).

Comment: the thread is a bit old, but I had the same problem and installed one previous version of TikzEdt (0.2). That worked for me.